# How to backup a Mac to a NAS (Samba-connected Windows share)?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, nas, samba

I'd like to find an (semi-)automated way to **backup** my **whole** MacBook Pro system and data to a network attached storage. The external storage is a Windows share I can access using Samba.

I can't use Time Machine, because it asks for a Time Capsule device - or *is* there a way to use Time Machine without a Time Capsule?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can 'force' Time Machine to backup to other mounted network shares. In Terminal, run the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

This should then allow you to backup to your SMB, AFP and NFS network shares. If they do not initially show up in Time Machine, mount them and then re-check.

Comment: Tried that command, Time Capsule still didnt see my NAS which is on a shared Windows LAN.  I remounted and even rebooted...

I can see (read/write) files on that NAS but I'd like to get Time Machine to actually begin backing up my one iMac to that drive like I have my Windows machines doing each night.